# How can I create object in abstract class without having knowledge of implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, abstract-class

Is there a way to implement the "CreateNode" method in my library abstract below?  Or can this only be done in client code outside the library?   I current get the error "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'ToplogyLibrary.AbstractNode"

```
public abstract class AbstractTopology<T>
{
    // Properties
    public Dictionary<T, AbstractNode<T>> Nodes { get; private set; }
    public List<AbstractRelationship<T>> Relationships { get; private set; }

    // Constructors
    protected AbstractTopology()
    {
        Nodes = new Dictionary<T, AbstractNode<T>>();
    }

    // Methods
    public AbstractNode<T> CreateNode()
    {
        var node = new AbstractNode<T>();  // ** Does not work **
        Nodes.Add(node.Key, node);
        }
    }
 }

    public abstract class AbstractNode<T>
    {
        public T Key { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractRelationship<T>
    {
        public AbstractNode<T> Parent { get; set; }
        public AbstractNode<T> Child { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what concrete node class do you *want* to be created? Is this perhaps something which should be left up to the concrete topology class? If so, you might want to make it abstract:

```
public abstract AbstractNode<T> CreateNode();
```

Then provide a concrete implementation in the concrete topology class.

Alternatively, you could make your class generic in the node type as well:

```
public abstract class AbstractTopology<TValue, TNode>
    where TNode : AbstractNode<TValue>, new()
```

Then you could implement CreateNode like this:

```
public AbstractNode<T> CreateNode()
{
    var node = new TNode();
    Nodes.Add(node.Key, node);
    return node;   
}
```

Personally I get a little suspicious of designs involving this many abstract classes, but perhaps you've got good reasons.

Comment: Sounds good. Will the caller using the method have to pass the type when they are using the mehod however?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create an instance of an abstract class, which is why you are receiving the error.

What you could do instead is declare `CreateNode` as an abstract method, and implement it in any descendant classes.

Comment: dang it, you've got faster fingers.

Answer (score 0):

define a protected pure abstract virtual method that CreateNode will call that the subclass return a new object

CreateNodeImpl  or something.